# Applozic Getting error in chatroom - contact applozic to active chat

Tags: swift, applozic

I am developing application where I am integrating applozic in iOS Swift

I can register users and even create the group, then I can also able to open the chatroom but there comes a message that

" Please contact Applozic to activate chat in your app "

[image: chatroom_screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you must be using a free or expired trial on release version app.